# COM - How to convert DATE data type to a formatted string in UTC

Tags: datetime, com, formatting, activex

How to convert DATE data type to a formatted string in UTC without using the library class 
COleDateTime. I do not have ATLComTime.h on my system

I would like to pass it as a DATE data type and return a string in 'yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ssZ'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VariantTimeToSystemTime then use the SYSTEMTIME structure to format a string.
There is no timezone information in a DATE. It just counts the number of days since midnight December 30, 1899.